# Multiple navigationControllers, call method in current "topViewController"

Tags: iphone, methods, callback, appdelegate

The question is in the title. I wrote "topViewController" to signify the fullscreen view the user is currently looking at. I'm looking for a generic way to do this from the App Delegate, regardless of whether the app uses 0, 1, or multiple navigationControllers.

I can solve this for the current app, but with special-case code. Sometimes you want to put a common method in the App Delegate and have it trigger a callback. I could use respondsToSelector, but it would then have a (to me) ugly lookup for the individually named callback methods.

It's simply an interesting question to me (surely the running app must know!) and a generic solution would be nice to have in your armory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reference to the navigation controller in the App Delegate containing the top view controller on which you'd like to call a method? If so, UINavigationController has a member called `topViewController`. You can cast that to your custom view controller class:

```
CustomViewController *customController = (CustomViewController *)[aNavController topViewController];
[customController myCustomMethod];
```

As I said, if you have a reference to the navigation controller in your App Delegate, this method will work.

If not, another approach could be to use NSNotificationCenter. Register for a custom notification name in the "topViewController," and post that notification from your App Delegate. If you register for the notification on each view controller when it becomes visible, and un-register when it disappears, only the visible view controller will receive the notification:

Register, in your case, probably in `viewDidAppear:`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myCustomMethod:) name:@"MyCustomNotification" object:nil];
```

Post the notification from your App Delegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyCustomNotification" object:myAccount];
```

Don't forget to remove the observer in `viewDidDisappear:`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"MyCustomNotification" object:nil];
```

Comment: Multiple Navcontrollers. Or it could have just a Tabcontroller and no Navcontrollers needed.